# How do I return multiple results of sum based using where and Group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to perform a query where I can get the sum of a column based on a where clause and group by a date but it is not behaving as I would expect and not sure why.

I have a table of transactions with:

a timestamp (**transaction_date**)
a value (**amount**),
a type (payin or **payout**),
pervious balance before transaction (**carry**),
and closing balance (**balance**).

Here is a JSON export of my table:

```
[
   {
      "id":"2",
      "type":"payout",
      "carry":"2340",
      "amount":"50",
      "balance":"2290",
      "transaction_date":"2014-09-15 00:00:00",
   },
   {
      "id":"1",
      "type":"payin",
      "carry":"340",
      "amount":"2000",
      "balance":"2340",
      "transaction_date":"2014-09-22 09:10:03",
   },
   {
      "id":"3",
      "type":"payout",
      "carry":"0",
      "amount":"50",
      "balance":"0",
      "transaction_date":"2014-09-22 09:10:03",
   },
   {
      "id":"4",
      "type":"payin",
      "carry":"1",
      "amount":"30",
      "balance":"1",
      "transaction_date":"2014-09-22 09:10:03",
   }
]
```

What I am trying to achieve is to get a single row for each date(calendar date, not a timestamp) which contains:
 
The date ( again calendar not timestamp),
initial carry before any of the days transactions,
sum of Payins for that date,
sum of payouts for that date,
the final closing balance for the day.

At the moment I am only getting a single result and it seems to ignore the group by (summing all payins and all payouts regardless of the rows date)

```
SELECT DATE(`transaction_date`) as day, 
SUM(amount) AS pay_in 
FROM transactions 
WHERE type='payin' GROUP BY day
```

this is the full query I am using (minus the carry and balance)

```
SELECT payins.day, payins.pay_in, payouts.pay_out 
From
    (SELECT DATE(`transaction_date`) as day, 
     SUM(amount) AS pay_in FROM transactions 
     WHERE type='payin' GROUP BY DATE(`transaction_date`)
     ) payins
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT DATE(`transaction_date`) as day, SUM(amount) AS pay_out 
     FROM transactions 
     WHERE type='payout' 
     GROUP BY DATE(`transaction_date`)
     ) payouts 
ON payins.day = payouts.day
Group By day
```

if it makes any difference I am using MAMP 3.0.4 on OSX 10.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the subqueries in this case, you can use `SUM` with `CASE`.  Also, you're grouping appears to be working fine for me returning 2 results for your sample data (see supplied fiddle):

```
SELECT Date(transaction_date) date,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type='payin' THEN amount END)) payinsum,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type='payout' THEN amount END) payoutsum
FROM transactions
GROUP BY date
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e190/3)